# CSS: Stopping div pushing content

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement a CSS menu and am having a problem with the menu pushing the other content/divs down when the menu expands.

http://www.confetti.ie/index2.aspx

Can anyone tell me what CSS I need to stop the main body content being pushed when the menu expands?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you describe in more detail?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The keyword is the CSS property `position: absolute`. It makes elements "float" over the other content. Absolutely positioned menu elements won't push the page content.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I still seem to be having a few problems. I've added position:absolute; to the submenu container, it still seems to push the main body and then teh body pops back up? Also how would I get the sub-menu container to appeatr over any other images on the page?

View problem here
http://bit.ly/bAcS56

Regards
Melt

Comment: @Melt the first I don't know, there must be some other element that gets resized by your script - can't really say which one.  The keyword for the second is the `z-index` property. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 8):

Use `position: absolute` for the one you want to be over and `position : relative` for the one don't want to move

Answer (score 6):

Use `position: absolute;` to throw the element (sub menu container) out of the document flow.